# Running a website project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net

This is my first time with Visual Studio. Basically I'm trying to open a Website Project but when i run it in Google Chrome (by clicking play button) it gives me the following error.

```
SqlException was unhandled by user code
Login failed for user '99karaokedb'.
```

I assume the database user is missing. Can anyone please tell me how can I fix it?

Your help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: We have no idea how your database and application is setup...

Comment: This is how it looks like: http://postimg.org/image/f4dlybw51/full/ and here is my web.cofig http://pastebin.com/ukjf99fc Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Provide the SE community with more data and you'll maybe get more help on this. Where exactly in the code is this failing?

Comment: Here is the error screen shot http://postimg.org/image/iph2iuejd/full/

Comment: Create the user. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx